# How to fill an array with objects from another array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to use an array of 52 objects (Cards with suits and values) and create an array that contains the same 52 objects but multiple times. (As if I had multiple decks of 52 cards in one big deck).

My default constructor filling the array of one deck looks like this:

```
public Deck() {
  allocateMasterPack(); //creates and fills the "model" deck
  cards = new Card[masterPack.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < masterPack.length; i++) {
     cards[i] = new Card(masterPack[i]);
  }
```

How can I do this so that I fill an array of two decks (104 card objects, 52-card deck repeated twice), or three, or four?

Comment: [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, you could do this using [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
int n = 2;
Card[] cards = IntStream.range(0, n)  // repeat n times
                        .mapToObj(i -> masterPack) // replace each i with the masterPack
                        .flatMap(pack -> Arrays.stream(pack)) // turn the Stream<Card[]> into a Stream<Card> by flattening it
                        .toArray(Card[]::new); // create a new array containing all the cards repeated n times
```

If you can't use Java 8, you could use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

> Parameters: 
>   src - the source array. 
>   srcPos - starting position in the source array.
>   dest - the destination array. 
>   destPos - starting position in the destination data. 
>   length - the number of array elements to be copied.

For example, if you wanted to copy the `masterPack` to a new deck with double its size, you could do:

```
int n = 2;
Card[] cards = new Card[masterPack.length * n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(masterPack, 0, cards, i * masterPack.length, masterPack.length);
}
```

This will loop twice, doing:

```
System.arraycopy(masterPack, 0, cards, 0, 52);
System.arraycopy(masterPack, 0, cards, 52, 52);
```

The first iteration will copy the `masterPack` elements to positions 0 to 51 and the second iteration to positions 52 to 103 in the `cards` array.

Your `Card` objects should probably be immutable, so there is no need to create new `Card` copies every time. Referencing the same 52 objects should be faster and take less memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
int repetitions;

for(int i = 0 ; i < masterPack.length * repetitions ; i++)
     cards[i] = new card(masterPack[i % masterPack.length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an ArrayList for your card game.

```
public Deck() {
int repetitions;     
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

for (int x = 0; x < repititions; x++)
    for (int i = 0; i < masterPack.length; i++) 
        cards.add(new Card(masterPack[i]));
```